# Escaping a single apostrophe while doing parameter expansion in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string:

```
Bearers | paths: '/org/........../Bearer/0'
```

I am trying to just get the 0 from the string.

I have the string assigned to a variable called `output_string`.

```
output_string="Bearers | paths: '/org/........../Bearer/0'"
```

Then I get the string after the last `/` which gives the output `1'`

```
BEARER_NUMBER={output_string##/}
```

Then I try and get the `1` from the  `1'`

```
BEARER_NUMBER={BEARER_NUMBER%'*}
```

However, after the apostrophe in the `BEARER_NUMBER%'*` it thinks everything from the star onward is part of a quote i.e. a quote that hasn't been closed.

Essentially, I am asking for an alternative way to get the second to last character, or how to escape an apostrophe. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' $output_string`
NF refers to the number of fields of the current record, printing $NF means printing the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the number, you can use regex and group references like this:

```
echo $output_string | sed 's/.*\/\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

This will look for numbers `[[:digit:]]\+` after a greedy match on everything till last `/` will occur and ignore everything after the numbers. The magic lies in defining the group and getting only the results of that group.

Comment: How can I equate this line to a variable? When I echo exactly what you wrote it works fine, but when I do `bearer=$output_string | sed 's/.*\/\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/g'`, when I `echo $bearer`, it comes out as blank

Comment: simply see this as a command which result you can save into a variable named `var` giving ticks (`\``): `var=\`echo $output_string | sed 's/.*\/\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/g'\``

Comment: I'll up vote this as the correct answer as I did ask either for a solution to the problem or an alternative solution. Thanks.